# When did the tilde first start to appear on standard keyboards?

Tags: keyboards

Someone at work made a joke, "He's so old that keyboards didn't have that key".

When would the <kbd>~</kbd> have first appeared on keyboards?

Comment: Can you possibly narrow the scope somewhat? You named 10 keys and there may be 10 different answers. How about re-wording along the lines of "When was the current de-facto standard keyboard first introduced"?

Comment: If you are old enough, you may have seen the [Space Cadet Keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-cadet_keyboard), so it's more like "he's so old that keyboards don't have those keys anymore". That also applies to lots of old keyboards with special keys.

Comment: Part of the problem in answering this question is that standard keyboards didn't really become a thing until the IBM PC days (even there, the standard IBM 5150 (XT) keyboard is markedly different from today's keyboards).  You could answer the question on when the oldest keyboard featuring the keyboard appeared, and hopefully we can figure out that answer.

Comment: @dirkt not a very assistive-friendly keyboard...

Comment: Interestingly enough, early typewriter keyboards didn't have the `1` (and sometimes `0`) keys because you could fake them with `I` and `O`! Look at [the Underwood typewriter keyboard on this page](https://notaphotoshoot.wordpress.com/tech/underwood/) for an example.

Comment: I don't know about tilde, but I remember using a model 33 teletype with a pre-ASCII keyboard.  It had an upward pointing arrow where the caret character is today (some of us still call it "up-arrow"), and it had a left pointing arrow where the underscore is today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tilde did apear as early as the late 1880s on typewriter and typseting keyboards.

Answer (score 6):

The IBM System/360 introduced in 1965 used the EBCDIC character set which included tilde.

The 1963 edition of the ASCII standard did not include the tilde character.  The 1965 edition included it, but it was at the position now occupied by "\" (backslash).  The 1967 edition of ASCII moved tilde to position 126 where it remains today.

So, it is fair to say that the tilde began to appear on standard keyboards in 1965.

Comment: EBCDIC waas especially designed to cover all ASCII character while maintaining compatibilitywith BCD equipment.

Comment: s/ASCII/US-ASCII/ I think

Comment: The 1963, 1965 and 1967 editions have mappings or allowable variations that are not included in US-ASCII.  For example the 1967 edition allowed "£" to be substituted for "#", and "¬" to be substituted for "^".  The term "ASCII" by itself can reasonably be assumed to mean "US-ASCII", but when a specific edition is referred to the name "US-ASCII" does not always apply.

Comment: IANA, for example, explicitly defines "US-ASCII" to refer to the 1986 edition of ASCII (aka ANSI X3.4-1986).